# How to use Google Maps API offline in Angular/Ionic App

Tags: android, angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 12 Ionic app that is using the Google Maps API via @angular/google-maps package (https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps#readme).  The application we are building will be used in areas where internet access can be spotty at best.  We are attempting to maintain functionality of the map when internet is lost.  IE, potentially cache or store the loaded map locally to reference should we go offline.

1. We are expecting the user to be online when we initialize the map and load any polylines & markers
2. Should the user then go offline, and navigate around the app, when coming back to the map we would like to show the map, polylines and markers that were previously loaded.

What currently is happening is the the component is being destroyed and then reloaded when navigated back causing a reload of the map which cannot happen because we are offline.  However, if we were able to cache or locally store that map, then we can load it from the cache/local until the user comes back online.

Using the package described above we are looking at trying to serialize the google.maps object to json for storage, however it is causing an issue.

```
let mapTest: google.maps.Map;
const center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: centerPoint.lat, lng: centerPoint.lng };

mapTest = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement, {
   center,
   zoom: 11
});
```

This is a basic typescript implementation as provided by the Google API Documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript).   When we attempt to stringify the map we get the following error

[image]

Same error shows if we stringify mapTest.data.

Question is, is there anything we can do to locally store the google.map object or the google.map.data object? This ultimately will be put onto an Android device using Ionic, is something like this possible with Native Android maps?  Or is this just not a feasible task at all

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript API cannot be used offline.

See feature request: [API feature to download a map for offline use](https://issuetracker.google.com/35827808).